# Parse geopoint swift not getting current location

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, geopoints

trying to use parses `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` to get current location when i send something to my backend. The code looks like

```
NSLog("Before block")
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        NSLog("inside block")
        if !error {
            // do something with the new geoPoint
        }
    }
```

and I never get my inside block on the console. I have Core Locations Framework installed and it allows me to do something like

```
let point = PFGeoPoint(latitude:40.0, longitude:-30.0)
```

If it helps i am not being requested for user location when I do the call above.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

and

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Put this keys in the info.plist

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in objective c. I placed this key in my info.plist

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

It worked fine in iOS 7 without that key but in 8 it won't.

Parse will most likely handle this situation when 8 is out.

Comment: You will also need to request authorization as well with core location to trigger the UINotification.