# Parse.com PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground not doing anything

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8

I'm using Parse.com iOS SDK, and I need the current location of the user, so I'm using the  function [PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground(...)](http://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html#//api/name/geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:).

The problem is: the block in the argument list is never called. Here is my code:

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground() {
    (point:PFGeoPoint!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    NSLog("Test log 1") // Never printed

    if point != nil {
        // Succeeding in getting current location
        NSLog("Got current location successfully") // never printed
        PFUser.currentUser().setValue(point, forKey: "location")
        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()
    } else {
        // Failed to get location
        NSLog("Failed to get current location") // never printed
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem. It's fixed in Parse 1.4.0.

Also you need to add the following key/value pair to your app's info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We want to send your location data to the NSA, please allow access to location services. (replace this text with whatever you want the dialog to say)</string>
```

References:

- [Parse SDK for iOS 8](http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/18/parse-sdk-for-ios-8-performance-and-security/)
- [CLLocationManager in iOS 8 - use of NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestAlwaysAuthorization)

Comment: I think this would be more prominent in their documentation as it will not work at ALL in iOS8 without these. THANKS so much for this post!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

[image: Fixed]

---

Got back with Facebook on this issue.

[image: Geopoint]

Similar question posted here: [Parse geopoint swift not getting current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173329/parse-geopoint-swift-not-getting-current-location)

Will update as they respond back.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

Click at your Project Targets/Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries/

```
This file must be listed: CoreLocation.framework 
if there is not click Add and select it from the list.
```

In your  ViewController.swift check this:

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

/Supporting Files/info.plist <- Click on this file

Click on + to add:
Key: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
Type: String
Value: Add a description

Click on + to add:
Key : NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
Type: String
Value: Add a description

check IOS Simulator 
   /Debug/Location/Apple 
                   here you must select something (none => error)

Comment: You could add a few words around this rather than just files and command titles. I understand what you say needs to be done, but most people probably won't...