# Can't retrieve geopoint with geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve the current user's current geopoint, but nothing happens when I call the `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:`. I can't log the `NSLog`'s from the block, however the other `NSLog` appears in the console.

```
- (IBAction)whereCurrentUser:(id)sender {

    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        if (geoPoint) {

            NSLog(@"GEOPOINT %@", geoPoint);

        }

        else

        {
              NSLog(@"ERROR");
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"BUTTON TAPPED");
}
```

Do I need to implement something else? The documentation is quite clear therefore I can't figure out what could be the problem.

Comment: What's the error say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution posted on [Parse.com PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground not doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441091/parse-com-pfgeopoint-geopointforcurrentlocationinbackground-not-doing-anything). Basically update Parse to the latest version and add the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key to your Info.plist, this is a change made in iOS 8 and is needed whenever you want to use an users location within your app.

Comment: Do you think it will work on iOS 7 also? It should work on iOS7-8

Comment: The NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key is only required on iOS 8, but updating Parse to the latest version should get it to work properly on iOS 7